# How do I find the definition of an overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand how portions of a large open source library work, and I am unable to find the definition of an overloaded operator. Using `Go To Definition` on the operator just takes me to the `typedef` at the top of the file.

Is there a way to find what code is actually used for an overloaded operator in VS or some other tool, or am I just stuck searching through the class hierarchy?

Comment: VS IntelliSense may need some time to build an index of the source files. But it sounds like you're looking up a type rather than an operator.

Answer (score 0):

If this operator is overloaded then VS will highlight it with different color. You need to click on operator body precisely and then select `Go To Definition`. Or set cursor at operator name (e.g. just before `+`) and press F12. If operator is built-in (e.g. int + int) then jumping to definition will show "Operator not overloaded" popup. Note that stated behavior is valid for VS 2017, in earlier versions of VS support for overloaded operator resolution was much more limited.

Comment: I'm using VS Community 2017. Putting the cursor immediately before the operator (* in this case) and pressing F12 still takes me to the `typedef`. The left and right sides are different classes that inherit from the same base class. The library makes heavy use of template classes, could that be throwing it off?

Comment: @MalikDrako If operator is part of template body then deducing real operator location is not very realistic. However of operator is inside of normal function then it should be located.